# mysql 5.7 loop through results of a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a simple MYSQL database server and want to use the data from the results of one complex query to fetch data from another table. This is the psuedo code:

```
originTable='SELECT id from original_table WHERE #some_complex_conditions'

for row in $originTable do
  SELECT profile,description FROM newTable WHERE id=${row.id}
done
```

I've seen examples online using cursors or while loops but nothing seems to work in mysql 5.7. Hoping that there's a simple way to loop through a table and use the rows like a JSON element. Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should write a proper JOIN.

Comment: Pease add sample data and expected outcome as text.